# How to customize checkbox style with react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap`. I'm trying to style a custom checkbox since it seems it makes it possible. Tho, it doesn't work. I'm doing what the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/forms/#forms-custom-checkboxes-and-radios)  tells me.

This is my code.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { t as typy } from 'typy';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { Form, FormCheck } from "react-bootstrap";
import { ErrorMessage } from "formik";

export type Props = {
  isChecked: Boolean,
  changeHandler: Function
}

export const Checkbox = ({
  isChecked,
  changeHandler
}: Props) => {


  return (
    <Form>
  {['checkbox', 'radio'].map((type) => (
    <div key={`custom-${type}`} className="mb-3">
      <Form.Check
        custom
        type={type}
        id={`custom-${type}`}
        label={`Check this custom ${type}`}
      />

      <Form.Check
        custom
        disabled
        type={type}
        label={`disabled ${type}`}
        id={`disabled-custom-${type}`}
      />
    </div>
  ))}
</Form>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

This is my css. I just want to see if it applies the style:

```
#custom-checkbox {
   background-color: red;
   width: 10rem;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341306/styling-a-form-check-checkbox-control-in-react-bootstrap. Also check this https://codepen.io/myleneb/pen/WMpyxG

Answer (score 1):

You can use .custom-control-input and .custom-control-label classes to apply custom style to the custom checkbox in react-bootstrap.